# In Russian, how do you say "no, scratch that!"?

Tags: выражения

> Perhaps, (blah blah blah) –  **no, on second thoughts, scratch that**.

In English, this particular use of the verb "scratch" comes in handy in conversation when you suddenly realise mid-sentence that a little *re-direction* in your thinking might be in order.

How do Russian speakers commonly express this idea colloquially?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Возможно, (бла-бла-бла)... **хотя нет, забудь (об этом).**

Or, if you have your second thoughts ready, then continue:

> Возможно, (бла-бла-бла)... **хотя нет, скорее...** (бла-бла-бла).

E.g.

> Наверное, я приду... **хотя нет, скорее** не приду.

Comment: instead of *"хотя"* - *"a"* can be used ***"а, (вообще-то) нет"***, if it's about appointment - ***"а, нет, отбой"***

Answer (score 5):

`Забей` is also acceptable in casual speech, like in:

> Хотя знаешь что, забей.

The other acceptable translation would be something like:

> Хотя знаешь, я тут подумал, проехали.

Comment: worth to be mindful that ***забей*** is inappropriate in a polite company, because it's an abbreviation of ***забей хуй***

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I'd rather disagree - it's extremely colloquial however it lost that connection in many contexts. But it's a valid comment, at least one should know it.

Comment: just to underscore - ***in a polite company***, it would have lost the connection if the phrase ***забить хуй*** had fallen into oblivion, instead it's well alive and kicking, so the link is quite apparent

Comment: I think that «забей» actually comes from «забудь»

Comment: забудь хуй? interesting, i'm sure there're ignorant people who have no clue where забей comes from, but they're not the audience by whom one should set one's standards

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка  Igor said nothing about `хуй` actually, it's you who stick to this version )))

Comment: indeed i just tried to mock the suggested etymology

Answer (score 2):

The verbs *most* usable for the translation of "scratch that" (1st person plural future tense, but also might be used in 2nd person singular/plural present imperative):

> "забудем; оставим; пропустим (это)"

The "on second thoughts" might be translatable as:

> "(хорошо) подумав" -- "[now] having thought (carefully) [of that]"; its close analogue: "если подумать" -- "if you think [of that]"

The "no," part might be translated as "хотя нет", like in Sergey Slepov's [answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/16711/10578), or it might be translated together with "on second thoughts" to the tune of:

> "no, on second thoughts," -- "или нет,".

Answer (score 1):

To highlight an oldish and somewhat bookish alternative: `впрочем`. It basically means "although", so

> Таким образом, трампампамция коагулирует ингибитор ульмотрона, хм, впрочем, нет. Вычеркните все после слов "таким образом".

The words `или нет`, `хотя`, `оставим` convey the same meaning.