# In Russian, how do you say when you suddenly, mid-sentence, come up with a more suitable phrasing as an afterthought?

Tags: словоупотребление

> If only I had just half of his... **no**, even a tenth as much courage as he does.

How do Russian speakers commonly deal with this "*or rather*" type of  mid-sentence gear shifting?

Comment: This is very similar to this question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/16710/2104

Comment: @SergeySlepov Yes. In this post, I'm looking for a less strong version of it (a slighter re-direction), since "no, on second thoughts, scratch that" is more like abruptly cutting short a comment right there and then.

Answer (score 3):

Using exactly the same construct: “Была бы у меня половина, нет, десятая часть его мужества”.

> Чтобы заснуть, надо десять, нет, сто раз прочесть про себя какие-нибудь стихи (Е. Гинзбург).

Answer (score 3):

Along with words like **... вернее**, **... точнее сказать**, (~= to be more exact) there's a typical self-correction phrase **да что там**...

> *Двадцать лет назад – **да что там**, десять лет назад на богача,
>   потратившего миллион долларов, чтобы избраться на выборную должность,
>   посмотрели бы с недоверием и подозрением.*
>
> *Он знал это, потому что помнил, какая тоска, **да что там** тоска, ужас
>   какой охватил его в Моршанске...* (Анна Берсенева, Ответный
>   темперамент)

Comment: Hi. Which of them would you personally use in my example?

Comment: _Да будь во мне хотя бы половина, да что там половина - одна десятая его смелости..._